# Funcion retorna None

Tags: python

Estaba aprendiendo sobre funciones y por alguna razón me return me retorna none

```
a = int(input("Tu numero 1:  "))
b = int(input("Tu numero 2:  "))
c = int(input("Tu numero 3:  "))

def menor(a,b,c):
    if a > b:
        n_menor = b
        n_mayor = a
    elif b > a:
        n_menor = a
        n_mayor = b
    elif n_menor > c:
        return c
    elif n_menor < c:
        return n_menor

t = menor(a,b,c)
print(t)
```

Intenta sacar el numero menor de esos 3 numeros pero al final solo retorna none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si a != b, la función no ejecuta ninguna `return`, por tanto retorna `None`.

Probablemente quisistes decir

```
a = int(input("Tu numero 1:  "))
b = int(input("Tu numero 2:  "))
c = int(input("Tu numero 3:  "))

def menor(a,b,c):
    if a > b:
        n_menor = b
        n_mayor = a
    else:
        n_menor = a
        n_mayor = b

    if n_menor > c:
        return c
    else:
        return n_menor

t = menor(a,b,c)
print(t)
```

o sea, primero determinar el menor entre a y b y luego compararlo con c.

No son necesarios los `elif` en este caso; el resultado no cambiara. Además tenías un error de lógica, pues si `a == b`, no inicializas `n_menor`, pues comparabas por estrictamente mayor o menor.

Ahora si hay un `return` garantizado.